# Texstudio has crashed due to a exception_access_violation

Tags: latex

`texstudio` has crashed due to a `exception_access_violation` and I don't know why. I am running on `version 2.8.8` and I don't know what shall I do. any help??

The error is shown below:

[image]

Comment: There should be a file called texstudio_backtrace?.txt in the %TEMP% directory with more information about this

Comment: @BeniBela it says:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 56f4e6 (TXS-Version 4828+:0a999280f5cb+ R )
[bt] 005455e0  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0056f4e6  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0056fe91  ??? error: 487
[bt] 00570055  ??? error: 487
[bt] 00570452  ??? error: 487
[bt] 004c814b  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0067963b  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0042bb22  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0047fbe3  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0074c105  ??? error: 487
[bt] 68a57273  ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv+1779
[bt] 0074e854  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0041e8a6  ??? error: 487
[bt] 00478953  ??? error: 487
[bt] 00478c23  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0072f  ??? error: 487

Comment: Something is off. Is it the qt5.3.1 version of 2.8.8 (default download)? qt version is shown in the about dialog

Comment: First aid: You can always try to recover. After that, you should save all files and restart TXS, because there may still be an inconstient  internal state which might lead to further problems. Additionally: Did you perfrom any specific action before the crash? Is it reproducible?

Comment: It happens every time when I run it for connected file(more than one tex file) but it runs normally for any single file.. Any help??